# open browser without clicking flutter button

Tags: flutter

[inappwebview Plugins](https://inappwebview.dev/docs/chrome-safari-browser/basic-usage/)

The in-app browser works when I click the button.
I want the action to be taken when the automatic application is opened without clicking the button.

```
 body: Center(
    child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          await widget.browser.open(
              url: Uri.parse("https://flutter.dev/"),
              options: ChromeSafariBrowserClassOptions(
                  android: AndroidChromeCustomTabsOptions(
                      addDefaultShareMenuItem: false),
                  ios: IOSSafariOptions(barCollapsingEnabled: true)));
        },
        child: Text("Open Chrome Safari Browser")),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if u have a Stateful widget add this in your initState method

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
       widget.browser.open(
          url: Uri.parse("https://flutter.dev/"),
          options: ChromeSafariBrowserClassOptions(
              android: AndroidChromeCustomTabsOptions(
                  addDefaultShareMenuItem: false),
              ios: IOSSafariOptions(barCollapsingEnabled: true)));
    },
    });
    
  }
```